# Is there a way to add additional independent fields such that they do not become a preexisting form's (DOM) children?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

Is there a way to add field elements that do not become a form's children? For example:

```
<form name="form" id="form">
<input type="text" name="text">

*<button type="button" onclick="load()">Load options</button>*<-- Need not become a child

<select name="select">
<option value="1">Option</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Is there a way to prevent the button element from becoming form "form"'s child?

Comment: Don't put it inside of the `<form>` element? I don't really understand what you're asking

Comment: Put it outside the form?

Comment: you can use the input's new form attribute to point to a different form, one that doesn't get submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to insert any tags (hard coded or dynamically inserted) withing the  tags then those will be automatically marked as child node according to DOM hierarchy.

The buttons can be placed independently without associating within the form to avoid it being a child node of the form.

```
<form name="form" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <select name="select">
        <option value="1">Option</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="load()">Load options</button>
```

Incase you would like to get the button to be positioned next to your textbox then you can use the same codes as you posted with slight modification.

```
<form name="form" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <button type="button" onclick="return load();">Load options</button>
    <select name="select">
        <option value="1">Option</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Now on your javascript function load() add return false at the end.

```
function load(){
    /*Your Codes*/
    return false;
}
```

This will prevent the button from processing your form after the load function is executed after click.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No. If button is inside of the form in HTML markup, it always will be form's child.
You can put this button outside of form and use absolute or relative positioning.
But if you just want to prevent form submitting on this button click, you can add ";return false" to click listener, or attach event by addEventListener and use preventDefault() of event object in event listener.